# GWT popup panel is Transparent??

Tags: java, gwt, popup, gwt2, uibinder

I am using Gwt ,

I have a Label. On the `onClick` Event there is a `PopupPanel`, Whre `tree` is added.
 the problem is the the `popupPanel` is transparent.

when the `popup.show` is executed , the `panel` behind `popupPanel` is seen through the `popupPanel`. How to avoid this.

```
    .
    .
        lblClass.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                            getPopupPanel();
                        }
                    });
private PopupPanel getPopupPanel(){

            popupPanel = new PopupPanel();
            popupPanel.setStyleName("documentClass-PopPup");
            int x =lblClass.getAbsoluteLeft();
            int y = lblClass.getAbsoluteTop();
            popupPanel.setPopupPosition(x, y+20);
            popupPanel.add(getCustomPropertiesTree());
            popupPanel.show();

        return popupPanel;
    }

CSS 

.documentClass-PopPup {
    margin: 2px 1px 1px;
    padding: 2px 1px 1px;
    border-top: thick;
    border-right: medium;
    border-bottom: medium;
    border-left: medium;
    font-size: 10pt;
    letter-spacing: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either define a background color for "documentClass-PopUp"

```
.documentClass-PopPup {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Or use

```
popupPanel.addStyleName("documentClass-PopPup");
```

instead of

```
popupPanel.setStyleName("documentClass-PopPup");
```